# Excel SUMIFS() using string with greater/less than symbols

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a table with a column that can take on values:

- <30
- 31-60
- 61-90
- '>90'

I want to use a SUMIFS() formula to calculate the totals for each group, but I believe the formula is trying to evaluate the greater/less than conditions. Here is what I am trying:

```
=SUMIFS( AP[item_balance], AP[days_late_category], "'<30'")
```

I tried using single quotes inside the double quotes, but that didn't work : "'<30'" and "'>90'".

Is there a way to calculate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put an `=` in front to let Excel know you want the string literal:

```
=SUMIFS( AP[item_balance], AP[days_late_category], "=<30")
```